# .Net Core 3.1 Dropdown list to show existing data

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

As you'll gather, I'm a relative beginner to web programming - moving on from Web Forms (ASPX) written in VB. My starter project is being developed in Visual Studio Code (latest version) as Razor pages using .Net Core 3.1 as I gathered that's now the most straightforward way. (I've avoided the full Visual Studio as this is a small project, I can't ask my organisation to pay for it and Microsoft is clear that the Community version isn't for use in "Enterprises", as it defines us.) I have coded in Basic, Pascal and Perl but am not an instinctive programmer. The complexity of a web application seems to me to have increased tenfold since "Classic ASP" and the requirement now to separate elements into View, Model and ViewModel.

Following examples on line, I've got my app to write to (seed data) and read from a MySQL database. However, parts of the View have defeated me. I've tried various examples of how to create and populate a dropdown list but none will compile or run for me because of missing elements, even after running "dotnet add package" and adding a reference to the relevant namespace.

Although my application is to run on Windows only, I decided I don't want a combo box because it's resource hungry (my application wouldn't compile anyway even after adding the necessary references and trying to rebuild.) I got in a tangle with tag helpers and HTML helpers and had a series of different errors. I haven't tried examples including "Viewbag" because I couldn't find a clear description of what it is, and at least one source advised against using it anyway.

It then struck me that I was overcomplicating things because my application had successfully read the data needed in the dropdown, as the attached image shows. It's there in the model (Home.cshtlml.cs) using BookIt_Context.cs and entities representing the two tables here in PC.cs and Location.cs. As the image shows, my sample data is available and can be shown in a table (for PC) and as plain text for Location (the list of place names run together at the top). However, trying various other techniques to show the dropdown kept giving errors telling me "Name" was not in the Model (although it clearly is).

Now the compile errors have gone but the dropdown for Location remains stubbornly blank. Can anyone tell me why? Does the data in Location (*public List Location {get; set; } = new List()*;
) need some kind of typecast to be shown in a dropdown? Apologies if I've missed something simple but I just can't see it.[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bfZ0.jpg)

```
@page
@model HomeModel // Definition of this lives in the corresponding .cs file
@{
    ViewData["Title"]="BookIt Home";
}

<section id="main">
    @foreach(var loc in Model.Location) { @loc.Name }
    <br>
    <select name="OurLoc" id="OurLocBox">
        @foreach(var loc in Model.Location) { <option value="@loc.Name"></option> }
    </select>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
    <tr> <!-- Header row -->
    <td><p><b>PC Name</b></p></td><td><p><b>Location</b></p></td><td><p><b>Workstn Name</b></p></td>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var pc in Model.PC)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><p>@pc.FriendlyName</p></td> <td><p>@pc.LocationID</p></td> <td><p>@pc.NetBIOSName</p></td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</section>
```

Home.cshtml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using BookIt.Data;
using BookIt.Models;

namespace BookIt.Pages
{
    public class HomeModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly BookIt_Context db;

        public HomeModel(BookIt_Context db) => this.db = db;

        public List<PC> PC {get; set; } = new List<PC>();
        public List<Location> Location {get; set; } = new List<Location>();

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            PC = await db.PC.ToListAsync();
            Location = await db.Location.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Could you please share also the code of HomeModel class as well the code of the controller ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. As the site said it was too long to add as a comment, I've edited my post to add the Model for home. I don't have a separate controller as I gather it's not needed in Razor pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the Value for the DropDownList items but not their texts.

```
@foreach(var loc in Model.Location) 
{ 
   <option value="@loc.Name">@loc.Name</option> 
}
```

Comment: This is definitely correct. On the other hand, I would say that there are also other problems based on `public List Location {get; set; } = new List()`.

Comment: Well looking at the screen shoot it seems that the list has been filled somewhere before reaching the view

Comment: You are correct. Just saw it. I haven't seen it before.

Comment: Yes there were some newbie errors in posting code inside text. Now should be fixed

Comment: Indeed...now it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Steve! Looks like I was so preoccupied there that I couldn't see the wood for the trees...will try to complete the rest of the logic of the page on my own.

Comment: Thanks. Steve answered my question. I stand by what I said about complexity - it turns out that I can't actually do anything with the dropdown value, I guess because "foreach" uses a local private variable. If anyone knows any tutorials that simplify all this, I'd be grateful for pointers to them!

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question with more details about your current problem. In this way a lot more people can see your post and help you

Comment: Thanks Steve. I've followed your advice.